# Iterate over current row values in kdb query

Tags: kdb

Consider the table:

```
q)trade
stock price amt  time
-----------------------------
ibm   121.3 1000 09:03:06.000
bac   5.76  500  09:03:23.000
usb   8.19  800  09:04:01.000
```

and the list:

```
q)x: 10000 20000
```

The following query:

```
q)select from trade where price < x[first where (x - price) > 100f]
'length
```

fails as above. How can I pass the current row value of `price` in each iteration of the search query?

While `price[0]` in the square brackets above works, that's obviously not what I want. I even tried `price[i]` but that gives the same error.

Comment: You are getting 'length error because 'x' and 'price' lengths are different. 'x'  length is 2 and price is 3 when it goes into your function.  To fix this , could you please give more details actually what you want to achieve with sample output result.

Comment: I want price to be a scalar when its passed into the indexing function of `x` above. It's value should be the value at each row that select iterates over. `x` and `price` are meant to have different lengths. Does that make sense?

Comment: so one thing is clear that in each iteration you want one price value in function. Is it same for 'x' or  each price value gets compared with full 'x' ?

Comment: I am thinking of `x` as a "vector": so if `x: 10 20` and say we are at the index `i:20` and `price[20] : 10` in my query, i want `x - price[20] : 0 10`.

Comment: try this:  price<x{ first where x} each (x -/:price)>100f

Comment: Thanks Rahul, although this works for the toy example above, I am not finding luck with the real problem at hand. `price` must be a scalar/atom corresponding to the current row being iterated upon. Any ideas?

Comment: In above condition, price on right end is behaving exactly the same like iterating over each row. So each price value is getting substraced from full x and used in further calculation. Do you mean that you want price on the left side of comparison to be scalar as well. Someting like this :  (price[i] <x[first where (x - price[i])>100f]

Comment: Ok, i think I figured it out: `price < x[first each (where each ((x -/:price)>100f))]` seems to work.

Comment: This is the same query that i mentioned before.